# MongoDB find if property in array of objects equals to another field

Tags: mongodb

This is the document model:

```
{
  foo: {
    bar: 1
  },
  some_array: [
    {
      xyz: 1
    },
    {
      xyz: 2
    }
  ]
},

{
  foo: {
    bar: 2
  },
  some_array: [
    {
      xyz: 123
    },
    {
      xyz: 321
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to find the documents that `'foo.bar'` equals to `'some_array.xyz'`.

As the example, only the first document should be fetched.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator to compare fields within the same document.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $in: [
      "$foo.bar",
      "$some_array.xyz"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Working MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lZJm0jsvTwJ)

Comment: Will it work on aggregation as well?

Comment: Yes. [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D_V3EB4PbU_)

Comment: When I try the opposite - `$nin` it doesn't work I got an error: `uery failed: (InvalidPipelineOperator) Unrecognized expression '$nin'`

Comment: `$expr` uses [aggregation expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#std-label-aggregation-expressions), which `$nin` is not. You can achieve the same result by wrapping `$in` with [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/not/#mongodb-expression-exp.-not).